# effects::effect not recognizing data in purrr::map

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

Consider a dataset like this:

```
library(lme4)
data(sleepstudy)
head(sleepstudy, 10)

   Reaction Days Subject
1  249.5600    0     308
2  258.7047    1     308
3  250.8006    2     308
4  321.4398    3     308
5  356.8519    4     308
6  414.6901    5     308
7  382.2038    6     308
8  290.1486    7     308
9  430.5853    8     308
10 466.3535    9     308
```

I'm trying to run some mixed-effects linear models when stratifying based on a grouping variable. I can do:

```
library(dplyr)
libary(tidyr)
library(purrr)

sleepstudy %>%
 group_by(grp = gl(2, n()/2)) %>%
 nest() %>%
 mutate(fit = map(data, ~ lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), data = .)))
```

obtaining:

```
  grp             data fit       
  <fct> <list<df[,3]>> <list>    
1 1           [90 × 3] <lmrMdLmT>
2 2           [90 × 3] <lmrMdLmT>
```

Now I would like to use the `effect()` function from `effects` library:

```
library(effects)

sleepstudy %>%
 group_by(grp = gl(2, n()/2)) %>%
 nest() %>%
 mutate(fit = map(data, ~ effect(term = "Days",
                                 mod = lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), data = .))))
```

however, I'm always getting an error:

```
Error in is.data.frame(data) : object '.' not found
```

When I use it outside of `tidyverse` context:

```
sleepstudy2 <- sleepstudy %>%
 mutate(grp = gl(2, n()/2))

effect(term = "Days", mod = lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), 
                                 data = sleepstudy2,
                                 subset = grp == 1))
```

then it works normally:

```
 Days effect
Days
       0        2        4        7        9 
252.2916 267.0686 281.8455 304.0110 318.7880
```

Any idea how to fix this problem and do it using the tidy approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the `effects()` function seems to have a real problem when the data you are using is not in the global environment. It's referenced in the "Warnings and Limitations" section of the `?effects` help page. They point to the "embedding" vignette from the `car` packages for possible work around. The workaround they suggestion is making a copy of data data in the global environment. It's not elegant but this works

```
poo <- sleepstudy %>%
  group_by(grp = gl(2, n()/2)) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(fit = map(data, function(x) {
    assign(".dta", x, env=.GlobalEnv)
    eff <- effect(term="Days", mod=lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), data=.dta))
    remove(".dta", envir=.GlobalEnv) 
    eff
  }))
```

Comment: It was very informative and helpful, thank you very much :)